# $pull from nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document structure. I'm trying to remove components from the components array with $pull. I can't work out how to select "mast" or "commsbox" from the following document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("23456yujbvfdfg"),
    "d": 1234567,
    "components" : [
        [
            "mast",
            {
                "foo":"bar"
            }
        ],
        [
            "commsbox",
            {
                "BLARN": "bAAA"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I've tried

```
db.sites.update({components: {$exists: true}, {$pull: { components.mast: {$exists: true} } }  }).pretty();
```

but I'm not able to select the component correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator to [**`$pull`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) from nested array

```
db.sites.update(
  { "components": { "$exists": true }},
  { "$pull": { "components.$": "mast" }}
)
```