# Pull from nested Array in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a document structure like this:

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "description": "foo",
  "vocabulary": [
    ["apple", "pomme"],
    ["hello", "bonjour"],
    ["bus", "bus"]
  ]
}
```

Now I want to pull an array inside the vocabulary array by specifying the first item, a.E.:

```
{"$pull": {"vocabulary.$": ["apple"]}
```

Which should remove the array `["apple", "pomme"]` from `vocabulary`, but this doesn't work.

I tried this ([$pull from nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521337/pull-from-nested-array)), but it did not work, it threw

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError:
The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query., full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 2, 'errmsg': 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very tricky question.

I think for this case `$` positional operator is not suitable.

Instead, you need an aggregation pipeline in `update` query.
Query (`$filter`) the values with the "apple" word is not (`$not`) existed (`$in`) in the `vocabulary` array field. Then `$set` to the `vocabulary` field.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "vocabulary": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$vocabulary",
          cond: {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                "apple",
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yn8v-ZDFM4b)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, that doesn't work on my server, but it works in the playground, which is pretty odd...